# Create a view with counts for unique values by type and at the end a row with count for all the types?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, I want to know is something like this is possible. My idea is to make a view out of another table that would be like this:

Table:

```
ID    Type
1      A
2      A
2      B
3      B
4      A
```

Supposed View:

```
Type   Sum
 A     3
 B     2
Both   4
```

It is counting distinct values, so that's why for A it has 3 unique values (ID: 1,2,3), for B is 2 (ID: 2,3), but for both it is not the sum but the unique values among all them that would add to 4.

The reason I want to do this view is because it saves some time for the user, because the data is loaded before the user interacts with it, I can upload this already calculated values a while before they use it and avoid doing those operations while they interact with it. Of course my data is of thousands of rows (still growing) and it has more than A and B types so I do save valuable time with the experience of the client if I can avoid doing this in the User Interface. Also, the "Both" calculation is because they can choose to show all the types, and I can't do a simple sum of the values of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
SELECT  Type, COUNT(*)
FROM    [Table]
GROUP BY Type

union all

SELECT  'Both',  COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM    [Table]
```

I have a feeling you over simplified your example. If this does not meet your requirement, do provide more sample data with different scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of SQL server function roll up which counts and does aggregate at the same time.

```
with Cte as (
select 1 as ID, cast('A' as Varchar(10)) as Type union all 
select 2 as ID, cast('A' as Varchar(10)) as Type union all 
select 2 as ID, cast('B' as Varchar(10)) as Type union all 
select 3 as ID, cast('B' as Varchar(10)) as Type union all 
select 4 as ID, cast('A' as Varchar(10)) as Type ) 

select  isnull(Type,'BOTH') Type , count(distinct ID) distinct_ids  from cte 
group by type with rollup
```

Output:

[image]